# Why doesn't text-overflow: ellipsis not work with display: inline-flex in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, drupal-7

When using long breadcrumbs e.g. `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, Firefox behaves differently from Chrome and Internet Explorer.

First I had to create special conditions to target specifically Firefox, like `display: inline-flex;` to make the text show, but the ellipsis still don't show.

for Chrome and IE:

```css
.easy-breadcrumb {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 860px;
  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#path .menu-breadcrumb,
#path .easy-breadcrumb {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

for Firefox

```css
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  .easy-breadcrumb {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  #path .menu-breadcrumb,
  #path .easy-breadcrumb {
    display: inline-flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 860px;
  }
}
```

The text is now showing on all browsers, except the `...` after the max-width of 860px on Firefox. Do you see a reason for this?

[image: please look at the rectangle in yellow and green. If I remove the span line it will work with the original code above]

If I remove the span in yellow and green, it will work with the above code, but I don't know if it's possible to remove it in Drupal for some reason.

Comment: What isn't showing in firefox? I tested it out and there seem to be differences between Chrome and FF, but the ... is showing

Comment: @YaakovAinspan The ... isn't showin on my Firefox

Comment: So this is what it looks like on FF: https://imgur.com/8eJ0G63, this is what it looks like on Chrome: https://imgur.com/HbZFtZx. Codepen: https://codepen.io/yak613/pen/LqGZKL

Comment: @YaakovAinspan your code is almost completely different though. I have uploaded a screenshot of the original html

Comment: And #breadcrumbs a:after {
  content: "/"; is not ideal, because if the title of the last link is big, as it is in my case, it won't make use of empty space as I see it.

Comment: Why doesn't it *not* work?

Comment: Because the selected html in the green+yellow rectangle is interfering. If I could delete it, it would work, but because it's dynamically generated by Drupal 7, I can't get rid of it. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. Turns out the issue was with the `display:inline-block;` property. Below is the part that I modified:

```
#breadcrumbs a,
#breadcrumbs span {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXdJzp) is the updated CodePen.